# Flink not commiting offsets to kafka

Tags: java, scala, streaming, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have a flink streaming job that is reading data from kafka and just logging it. I have enabled checkpoints.

I cannot see the commited offsets in kafka instead i'm getting below error.

Any help is much appriciated.

```
{$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --new-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group flink-consumer-group
Error while executing consumer group command Group flink-consumer-group with protocol type '' is not a valid consumer group
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Group flink-consumer-group with protocol type '' is not a valid consumer group
at kafka.admin.AdminClient.describeConsumerGroup(AdminClient.scala:152)
at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$KafkaConsumerGroupService.describeGroup(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:308)
at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$ConsumerGroupService$class.describe(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:89)
at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$KafkaConsumerGroupService.describe(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:296)
at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$.main(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:68)
at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand.main(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala)}
```

Versions

```
kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0 (server with) flink-connector-kafka-0.10_2.11
```

Comment: I observe the same issue, curious if you were able to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured that flink does commit the offsets to kafka on chekpointing by default, because value [FlinkKafkaConsumer#setCommitOffsetsOnCheckpoints](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.html#setCommitOffsetsOnCheckpoints-boolean-) is true by default.

Unfortunately these offsets are not visible via the kafka-offset checker cli.

We implemented a scala kafka consumer that connects to kafka with same consumer group but doesnot subscribe to the topic to get the offsets from kafka.

*Note:* Starting from Kafka version 0.9 consumer Flink Kafka exports all standard metrics, see [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-connector-metrics).

Answer (score 1):

Flink handles the offsets by it's own. The offsets which are committed to kafka (or zookeeper in older versions or setups) are more or less just for your info or for monitoring purposes.

Your error looks like you mixed up different kafka versions (broker version vs. client version). Maybe you can double check this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply TobiSh.

I understand that flink doesn't use the commited offsets but on a restart the application without a savepoint it should use the committed offsets wihch is not happening in my case.

I'm using kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0 (server with) flink-connector-kafka-0.10_2.11

Comment: Hi @mukh007 do you have some source-code where we can reproduce this behaviour. Also the config of the flink cluster and the kafka properties would be useful.

Comment: One more thing. Do you find something like this in your logfiles:

Partition {} has no initial offset; the consumer has position {},  so the initial offset will be set to {}